# Is there a working excel sheet module for Python 3.4?

Tags: python, excel

I've been looking around for a python module to work with excel sheets. So far I've come across the following:

- openpyxl
- xlsxwriter
- xlrd
- xlwt
- xlutils

The issue I'm running into is that any time I import these modules I get an error saying that they don't exist.
Example: `ImportError: No module named 'xlutilx'`

This is the first time I've ever had this issue with importing modules with Python so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You probably don't have them. You need to download modules that you don't have in order to use them. For instance, the [openpyxl website](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) includes details of how to install it.

Comment: Do I have to download them to any specific directory for them to work?

Comment: You' ll have to install them.

Comment: @ShaunAran Try the instructions on the [openpyxl website](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/)

Comment: Excel sheets can be converted to CSV files very easily. CSV files are much much easier to handle in python.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these modules are still working with Python 3. All you need to do is to actually install them on your computer.

If you are not sure what to do, I suggest using a prepackaged Python distribution such as Anaconda which already includes most of them: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/excel

Note that such a distribution is actually separated from your current installation. See the start of the user guide for a more complete explanation.